# Exception: bad escape \p at position x

Tags: python, neural-network, allennlp

I am trying to run allennlp package's prediction using a model which I have trained over my training data. However, at the beginning of the process, this exception comes up and halts the program.

> raise source.error('bad escape %s' % escape, len(escape))
>   sre_constants.error: bad escape \p at position 257

Also, when I open an allennlp environment, I'm getting another error:

> 2019-04-01 12:20:43,879 - INFO - allennlp.common.params -
>   dataset_reader.lazy = False Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I'm doing a sequence-to-sequence task where the training data is a bunch of 0 and 1's (src and target) using the following command:

```
CUDA_VISBILE_DEVICES=1 python -m allennlp.run train  
                       allennlp_config/simple_tagger.json 
                       --serialization-dir models/last
```

And in prediction:

```
python -m allennlp.run predict models/new1/model.tar.gz 
                               data/test.src.txt 
                               --output bu-out.txt 
                               --cuda-device 0 
                               --batch-size 5
```

To be specific, I try re-producing the results in this repo: https://github.com/sebastianGehrmann/bottom-up-summary